# What to use for subdocuments ID's in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have collection with documents in MongoDB database. Each document (see below) has `_id` and might contain number of subdocuments in `grades` array. I was wondering what is the best practice to create unique ID's for these subdocuments? I could use `ObjectId` or generate some random ID's on application level, so what would be the best approach? BTW I use NodeJS with Mongo native driver.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556c42c0563c07735bcd87dd"),
    "name" : "Homer Simpson",
    "grades" : [
// use ObjectId as below?
        {
            "id" : ObjectId("556c42c0563c07735bcd87db"),
            "level" : 0
        },
// or randomly generated string?
        {
            "id" : "556c42c0563c07735bcd87dc",
            "level" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a unique ID? In your example, is there nothing unique about each of the subdocuments? If not, then why do you want to identify each one? It's pretty much the same thing as `{"grades" : [0, 1]}`.